# How to properly install Nfsd for Openedx in Ubuntu 16

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, openedx

Openedx is expecting nfsd as per the image attached.

[image]

So, I tried installing it using this link:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04

But below command is not working:

```
> sudo nfsd status
sudo: nfsd: command not found
```

But I tried prepending word "service"

```
sudo service nfsd status
● nfsd.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Ultimately I want to install openedx without errors. How can I fix my nfsd 
 installation so I can use it for installing openedx ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`nfsd` status works in `macOS`.

On ubuntu, `/etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server` status should work.

This step mentioned in the open edx devstack installation is to ensure that the nfs services are running, so that the code repository in the local machine can be shared to the virtual machine via nfs mount point.